# Scala Play - calling controller method from view doesn't load a new page

Tags: ajax, scala, playframework, jscript

I display information, gather some user's input, and call a controller method using ajax/java script call from the view. However, instead of displaying a new/different html page, the controller method returns back to the original html page that I called jscript from.

Is this because of ajax call? How do I make sure that controller method would display the html file it's supposed to, instead of staying on old html page?

Comment: You're really going to need to provide some more details to get much help. But sounds like you need to use create a separate controller method for the POST action generated by your form.

Comment: Yes, I have a controller method, which gets called. The problem is that Ok(nextveiw.scala.html) does not bring up the next view. Instead, the old page keeps being displayed.

Comment: fix the tags... what is playback for you?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you want to do is to open a different url than the one you are on. To do that you do not use ajax. Instead try using javascript to change `window.location` to tell the browser to go to the url (or 'call your controller'). It looks like this:

```
window.location.assign("/your/controller/url"); // or
window.location = "/your/controller/url";
```

There is more to read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

You can think of ajax as a separate little browser that lets you call the web server but letting you handle what comes back with javascript rather than always showing it to the user. So if you want to do the call with ajax but get the response HTML into your page, you are responsible for taking that response and inserting it into the DOM.